# Como hacer varias consultas en un solo archivo PHP

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

me explico lo que quiero es realizar varias consultas a la base de datos en un archivo PHP,
Estoy trabajando en una aplicación android en donde obtengo el id de de una categoría y muestro los resultados en una activity, sin embargo no quiero crear 100 activitys, 100 URL y 100 archivos PHP para obtener los resultados, lo que quiero es hacer todo en un mismo archivo y también en una misma clase JAVA así como también utilizar la misma URL (Estoy trabajando con una base de datos remota).
Bueno sin mas aquí muestro como estos haciendo la consulta desde mi archivo PHP

```
<?php

require "conn.php";

/* En esta parte hago la consulta ( Nada nuevo ) solo recalacar que el id_categoria = 2
 significa que quiero obtener todos los exámenes que tienen el id_categoria = 2
 Cuando quiera obtener todos los exámenes donde el id_categoria sea igual a '3' entonces
 es ahí donde radica el problema simplemente no se como hacer eso otra consulta en el mismo archivo 
 PHP */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM examenes where id_categoria = '2'";

$query = $mysqli->query($sql);

$datos = array();

while($resultado = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $datos[] = $resultado;
}

//echo json_encode($datos);
echo json_encode(array("Usuarios" => $datos)); ?>
```

Luego tengo mi clase java MainActivity.java
Si vamos al grano esta es el metodo que obtiene la consulta y llena mi recyclerview con los datos que estas guardados en la base de datos

```
public void obtenerUsuarios() {

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    //Este stringRequest obtiene la URL de mi archivo PHP 
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.URL_USUARIOS),
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Usuarios");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            listaUsuarios.add(
                                    new Usuario(
                                            //En esta parte obtengo los campos de mi base de datos
                                            jsonObject1.getString("id_examen"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("nombre_examen"),
                                            jsonObject1.getString("precio_examen")
                                    )
                            );
                        }

                        adaptador = new AdaptadorUsuarios(MainActivity.this, listaUsuarios);
                        rvLista.setAdapter(adaptador);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    );

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

**En conclusion**

**Tengo otras 9 categorias de examen mas y no quiero hacer 9 veces mas el proceso anterior, lo que quiero es obtener los 9 id_categoria en el mismo archivo PHP y cuando haga el intent al main activity el recyclerView se llene mediante el id_categoria 1, 2, 3, etc**

**De antemano muchas gracias**

Comment: Manda `id_categoria` como parámetro sobreescribiendo el método `StringRequest.getParams()`. En php pasa a la consulta SQL el valor del parámetro  con `$_POST['id_categoria']`.

Comment: Me fue de mucha ayuda, gracias!!